# Remove all elements that have at least one duplicates completely out of a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, filter

**Introduction**

I am a Belgian software engineer working in a company that is producing press brakes. I now have an interesting problem, where I would like to know the best solution, performance is really imporant in my working context. I think it might be interesting for other programmers as well.

**Data**

- I have a list with a bunch of objects of class type "CS3DLine".

  ```
  List <CS3DLine> ListParallelLines = new List<CS3DLine>();
  ```
- I also have a custom method which takes two of these objects as arguments and returns a boolean telling if this two objects are equal or not.

  ```
  public static bool IsSameLineIn3D(CS3DLine povleft, CS3DLine povright)
  ```

**Wanted**

I would like to get a FilteredListParallelLines where the CS3DLines that are equal are *completely* filtered out of the list.

**Remarks**

- On Internet I found examples (e.g. on this page on [dotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/duplicates)) with the Distinct-method and IEqualityComparer, but in these cases only the duplicates where deleted, not the originals that had the duplicates.
- I know I can also try to solve this iteratively, but I am afraid that if the list contains a huge amount of objects, this will result in a bad performance.

Comment: You need to define an `IEqualityComparer<CS3DLine>` which implements not only testing for equality, but also a consistent **hash code** for each line instance. Then you will be able to use set-based methods to eliminate the dupes.

Comment: No matter how you do it, removing items from a list will always be hard for multithreading. Do not worry about performance before you have measured it.

Comment: Perhaps a groupby on multiple property and filter where count is 1? Perhaps the issue is that the list already contains a huge amount of object. With proper IEqualityComparer and get hash there are data structure that won't accept duplicate . It will thin your list

Comment: If I understand correctly, if there are two or more instances of lines that are equal, they are ***all*** discarded. Correct?

Comment: Indeed, @spender, this is correct. They should **_all_** be discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following is a set-based approach that might satisfy your requirements. I can't vouch for performance.

Can be simplified if the ordering of the list is not of importance.

In the absence of a definition of `CS3DLine`, I've provided an example for my own Line class.

As ever, when using set-based methods, it's best that the line class is immutable.

```
void Main()
{
    List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
    var comparer = LineEqualityComparer.Instance;
    var filtered = lines
        .Select((line, idx) => new { line, idx })
        .GroupBy(x => x.line, comparer)
        .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
        .SelectMany(g => g)
        .OrderBy(x => x.idx)
        .Select(x => x.line);
}

class Line
{
    public int X1 { get; }
    public int Y1 { get; }
    public int X2 { get; }
    public int Y2 { get; }
}

class LineEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Line>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<Line> Instance { get; } = new LineEqualityComparer();
    public bool Equals(Line x, Line y)
    {
        //fill-in the blanks
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Line obj)
    {
        //fill-in the blanks
    }
}
```

On a large dataset, you *might* be able to get better performance on the query by strategically placing a `.AsParallel()` *somewhere* in the chain of linq methods.

Comment: Hi @spender, I used this solution and after testing I can confirm that it is working as it should. Thank you very much. I omitted the OrderBy as ordering is not important in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For complex objects you need to override Equals And GetHashCode after that you can simply compare it

http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/687/overriding-equals-in-c-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

In the first step you need to create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer` for your `CS3DLines` class.

This might look close to this:

```
public class CS3DComparer : IEqualityComparer {
    public bool Equals(CS3DLines a, CS3DLines b) {
        return IsSameLineIn3D(a, b);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(CS3DLines line){
        // You do not need to use all properties of line to calculate the 
        // hashCode. If performance is not good enough you can experiment by 
        // adding and removing properties from the hash code calculation.

        var hashCode = line.Property1?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (line.Property2?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (line.Property3?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Next to get an unsorted list of all elements in your `ListParallelLines` collection you can call this code:

```
var singles = ListParallelLines
    .GroupBy(line => line, new CS3DComparer())
    .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => group.Key)
    .ToList();
```

`singles` is now a list of all lines that have no duplicates in `ListParallelLines`.

For a possible speedup through parallelization you can try using PLINQ by starting the LINQ Query with a call to `AsParallel()`.

```
var singles = ListParallelLines
    .AsParallel()
    .GroupBy(line => line, new CS3DComparer())
    .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => group.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to your requirement to remove items that have any duplicates completely from the list one approach is to first group your set and then to filter based on any groups that have more than one item.

Performance for this kind of filtering is always limiting but to save time when grouping and having to run equality comparisons if you have your object maintain its own hash to group by ahead of time this will reduce the load at time of wanting to filter and the hash would need to be consistently updated through changes to the given instance. The considerations would be different if your hardware is the limit thus you would not want to have to store hashes for all items in memory or if it is the speed you are concerned about. Storing hashes and not calculating them is not ideal due to possible moving parts within your code that could inadvertently not trigger a hash update but if performance is a large factor it may help if carefully implemented.

```
var results = ListParallelLines.GroupBy(x => x.EqualityHash).Where(x => x.Count() == 1);
```

This would given a hash return you a list of items that have no duplicates what so ever.

There is a default implementation of GetHashCode() but it has a pretty high chance of conflicts and I have seen an issue in the past which caused a massive headache because of it so try to avoid using it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Comment: There's no difference between overriding `GetHashCode` and providing your own uniquely named property that does the same (other than turning out non-standard code). Using only a hash-code to determine equality is misplaced. Any hash table requires a hashcode ***then an equality method*** in the case that the hashes of two items match. Take a read of the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) entry about collision resolution to understand why both hash and equality are required.

Comment: The point of not using an on demand generated hash is to save time at the point of filtering the list so providing a property which holds a value at all times that does not need computing at the point of access does serve a purpose on large data sets given the focus on performance. Whilst less ideal as with denormalization of data it serves a purpose. Collisions are unlikely (but still possible) and choosing the right hashing method would help mitigate that. If performance is the focus the very low chance of a collision may be an acceptable trade off.

Comment: Further to that to avoid the issue entirely but still save on overhead you could do the equality checks on only those with matching hashes which greatly reduces the amount of potentially unneeded checks if accuracy is vital. If performance were not the point of the question I would recommend implementing an EqualityComparer exactly as you have done. If I have missed something I would be interested to hear your take on it.